# Where can I find gre practice test powerprep solutions?

Tags: gre

Where can I find worked out solutions provided by ETS for the GRE practice tests in the powerprep software?

Thanks.

Comment: I Googled "Solution ETS for the GRE practice tests in the powerprep software" and then I followed the link and found [Explanation Videos for Official GRE Material](http://magoosh.com/gre/2013/explanation-videos-for-official-gre-material/)

Comment: I have no intention to make it an answer because I did not go through the practice test and explanation myself. If you follow the link I provide above and find it useful, please answer your own question.

Comment: I stated by the ETS. I am already aware of those solutions.